# Python pandas splinting strings, adding rows, different for each column

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I hope someone with more knowledge than I can provide some wisdom before I pull all my hair out.

I have a dataframe which looks like this

```
Date    Unit    Length  AM/PM   unit_new
5   Monday\r13 January  12345H\rEngineering - Unit 1: Engineering Principles\r23456H\rHealth and Social Care - Unit 2: Working in Health\rand Social Care   2h 00m\r1h 30m  morning
6   Tuesday\r14 January 34567H\rBusiness/Enterprise and Entrepreneurship -\rUnit 3: Personal and Business Finance\r12345L\rApplied Human Biology - Unit 1: Principles of\rHuman Biology\r23456K\rConstruction and the Built Environment -\rUnit 1: Construction Principles  2h 00m\r1h 30m\r1h 30m  morning
7   Wednesday\r15 January   34567H/1C\rApplied Science/Forensic and Criminal Investigation\r- Unit 1: Principles and Applications of Science I -\rChemistry\r12345H\rSport and Exercise Science - Unit 1: Sport and Exercise\rPhysiology    0h 40m\r1h 30m  morning
```

Now the problem I have it that the 'Unit' column has multiple records worth of data on each row, but it is not consistent in the number of records on a row. The 'length' column has the same setup as the 'Unit' column. The 'Date' and the 'AM/PM' columns have a single entry.

This image better explains the problem. Row 5 has two records one for Enginering and one for HSC, the length column follows suit. The 'Date' and 'AM/PM' are the same for both records. Line 6 has three records and line 7 has two.

[image: dataframe]

Now what I am trying to do is split each record onto its own row. In trying to do this I have tried a number of different methods and not made much ground.

**Method idea one**
My first thought was to try and add new row(s) under the relevant row and extract the data from 'Unit' and 'Length' columns while copying the data from 'Date' and 'AM/PM' columns. This proved to be trick as inseting into the middle of the df it more complicated.

**Method idea two**
Next I thought to append rows to the bottom of the df and sort later.

So I wrote a function that did a count of the number of records on each row and output to a series.

```
def code_count_func():
    code_count = df.Unit.str.count('\d{5}\w').subtract(+1)
    # drop na's to stop error
    code_count.dropna(inplace = True) 
    # converting to int 
    code_count = code_count.iloc[0:].astype(int)
```

The code below is what I am trying at the moment it splits into a list of strings in a new column called 'unit_new' but the regex is not quite capturing as per my colourful image.

```
for index, row in code_count_func().iteritems():
    df['unit_new'] = df.Unit.str.split('(\d{5}\w)')
```

The second issue is that I also am not sure how to finsh the program. I was thinking using the `DataFrame.explode` method but I am unsure how to use this on the 'Unit' and 'Length' columns but just copy from 'Date' and 'AM/PM' columns.

Can someone please give me some guidance on how to use use the explode method or similar. Also if anyone is able to help with my regex, please.

A little more on the regex issues. So the one thing that is consistent with the pattern in the 'Unit' column is the five digit number and one letter e.g. 12345K which is used at the start of each new record. So looking at row 5 I want to get this:-

12345H\rEngineering - Unit 1: Engineering Principles\r
23456H\rHealth and Social Care - Unit 2: Working in Health\rand Social Care

I have tried a number of patterns but no luck.

**Required output**

[image: output]

Comment: what does the desired output look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work and could be better with a more refined regex. My columns might be off from the copy/paste process but the logic should be correct

Get the units

`df['Unit'] = df['Unit'].str.split('(.+?(?=\d{5}))')`

Get the lengths

`lengths = df['AM/PM'].str.split(r'\\r').explode()`

Explode the Units, remove the empty entries from the regex and concat the lengths back to the dataframe

`df = pd.concat([df.explode('Unit').query("Unit != ''"), lengths], axis=1)`

```
            Date           ...                                               Unit   AM/PM
5     Monday\r13  January  ...  12345H\rEngineering - Unit 1: Engineering Prin...  2h 00m
5     Monday\r13  January  ...  23456H\rHealth and Social Care - Unit 2: Worki...  1h 30m
6    Tuesday\r14  January  ...  34567H\rBusiness/Enterprise and Entrepreneursh...  2h 00m
6    Tuesday\r14  January  ...  12345L\rApplied Human Biology - Unit 1: Princi...  1h 30m
6    Tuesday\r14  January  ...  23456K\rConstruction and the Built Environment...  1h 30m
7  Wednesday\r15  January  ...  34567H/1C\rApplied Science/Forensic and Crimin...  0h 40m
7  Wednesday\r15  January  ...  12345H\rSport and Exercise Science - Unit 1: S...  1h 30m
```

Comment: Genius, it works! Got to love pandas. I understand some of the logic but not all. I am wondering why I can not do this ```units = df['Unit'].str.split('(.+?(?=\d{5}))').explode().query("Unit != ''")
lengths = df['Length'].str.split('\\r').explode()
df = pd.concat([units, lengths], axis=1)``` 
*or this*
 ```df['Unit'] = df['Unit'].str.split('(.+?(?=\d{5}))')
df['Length'] = df['Length'].str.split('\\r')
df = pd.concat([df.explode('Unit').query("Unit != ''"), df.explode('Length').query("Length != ''")], axis=1)```?

Comment: `explode` changes the shape of the original `df` so you can't just reassign it. You could do them separate and concat at the end but then you lose your other columns. If this works please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) so this can be closed